# Cant find non-standard header includes

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, clang, newlib

I am not using standard `gcc` headers. I am building with `-nostdlib` and `-nostdinc` options. These options force the compiler to not use standard headers.

I am using `newlib` for my custom kernel development. `newlib` contains headers and other libs.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30792552/13014162

The error when I type `make`:

```
lib/builtins/lib_int.h:29:12: fatal error: 'stdint.h' file not found
#  include <stdint.h>
           ^
1 error generated.
Makefile:90: recipe for target 'lib/builtins/kern_lib.o' failed
```

So, when building the compiler should pick up the `stdint.h` from `newlib` (instead from standard header). Why is it not picking it?

This project has already been built by others previously. So there is something in my setup that is wrong. I believe that include paths and other things are correctly setup because others are able to build it.

Can someone point to me specifically how to **USE** `newlib`. I checked that `newlib` has `stdint.h` inside it.

Comment: Because you used `-nostdlib` and `-nostdinc`. Just specify the include directory and link with newlib object library like you would with any other library.

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes with `-nostdlib` it should not pickup from standard headers. BUT instead, it should pick up from `newlib`. My question is why it is not picking from `newlib`

Comment: `BUT instead it` why? The `-nostdlib` doesn't do "don't pick standard, pick newlib". It only does "don't pick standard". Nothing else is picked.

Comment: @KamilCuk. That is a requirement. Also see the link that I have given in my post that will answer you. In OS development we avoid using standard headers

Comment: @KamilCuk. Yes so `-nostdlib` has done its job its of "dont pick standard". I want to know how the rest of the job will be done: "pick newlib"

Comment: It was already told to you: `specify the include directory and link with newlib object library like you would with any other library`. That is, use `-I` and `-L` to tell the toolchain where the newlib headers and libraries are installed.

Comment: What is the compiler command line that you execute to get the error you show?  It must be missing the crucial information — or the crucial information must be misspecified (which is tantamount to the same problem).

Comment: if your toolchain has configures spec file for the newlib you may use `"-specs=nosys.specs" ` if not define your  own one https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html some examples here: https://github.com/littlekernel/newlib/blob/master/libgloss/libnosys/nosys.specs

Comment: @NeedSomeLuck headers do not harm. OS developers usually do not use standard library which is something completely different. stdint.h is one of the headers which should be uses instead of homebrewed `BYTE`, `WORD`, `DWORD`, `U8`, `u8`, `U8PTR_t` and similar monsters

Answer (score 1):

From the newlib [README.txt](https://sourceware.org/newlib/README) file:

> To compile a program against shared newlib:
>
> ```
> gcc -nostdlib $(target_install_dir)/lib/crt0.o progname.c -I $(target_install_dir)/include -L $(target_install_dir)/lib -lc -lm -lgcc
> ```
>
> To run the program, make sure that $(target_install_dir)/lib is listed
>   in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.
>
> To create a static binary linked against newlib, do the following:
>
> ```
> gcc -nostdlib -static $(target_install_dir)/lib/crt0.o progname.c -I $(target_install_dir)/include -L $(target_install_dir)/lib -lc -lm
> ```

The above is written in Makefile format, with `progname.c` being the name of the source file to compile, and `$(target_install_dir)` being the directory where newlib was installed into.  If you are unsure, you can run `find ~/ /usr /lib* -name crt0.o`; newlib should be installed in two directories above one of the outputs.  If that command doesn't output anything, you haven't installed newlib yet.

Personally, I'd try with something like the following Makefile:

```
INCNEWLIB := /usr/include/newlib
LIBNEWLIB := /usr/lib/arm-none-eabi/newlib
CRT0      := $(LIBNEWLIB)/crt0.o
CC        := /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc
CFLAGS    := -Wall -Wextra -O2
LDFLAGS   :=

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -nostdlib -I $(INCNEWLIB) $^ -c -o $@

# For dynamically linked binary executables:
dynamic-bin: your.o object.o files.o here.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -nostdlib $(CRT0) $^ -L $(LIBNEWLIB) -lc -lgcc $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

# For statically linked binary executables:
static-bin: your.o object.o files.o here.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -static -nostdlib $(CRT0) $^ -L $(LIBNEWLIB) -lc $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
```

Note that this forum eats tabs, and Makefiles need to be indented with tabs, so if you copy-paste the above, fix the indentation using e.g. `sed -e 's|^  *|\t|' -i Makefile` .

The above paths are for Debian/Ubuntu/Mint ARM newlib, edit them to match your system and personal preferences.

You can override any of the variables at the command line.  For example, `make CRT0=/usr/lib/arm-none-eabi/newlib/thumb/v7e-m/fpv5/hard/crt0.o` uses a different startup routines for the binary executable (v7e-m hard-fpv5).